# Create text field that counts the number of words live in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I would like to create a text field that counts the number of words in it live as someone is typing, and shows this number in view, and when hitting submit, it saves the number of words but not the text itself. Any tips on achieving this?

Thanks!

Comment: var numberOfWords = text.split(' ').length;

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic. "How do I do that?" doesn't fly.

Comment: How is this not a question? Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to do it in much less code and without using global variables, but that's the way they do it in official Meteor tutorial, so it should be familiar to you already.

I've provided [working example on MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/QPg8pWy5Y6XmGZ4gb/Word%20counter).

HTML:

```
<body>
  <input type="text">
  <p>{{counter}}</p>
</body>
```

JS:

```
Template.body.helpers({
  counter: function () {
    return Session.get('count');
  }
});

Template.body.events({
  'keydown input': function () {
    Session.set('count', $('input').val().split(' ').length + ' words');
  }
});
```